# How To hide LeftCalloutAccessoryView in MKAnnotationView in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to hide LeftCalloutAccessoryView

[image]

As you see on the left side (white background),  I want to hide/remove this area. I tried to do many things but doesn’t work. I just want to use right area.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked too for a while , but eventually found:
        `mkAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView.isHidden = true`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly question but have you tried just doing

mkAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil

Comment: yes i tried.. not nil but null because i am using xamarin.ios. and this white area still there. But there should be a solution. I saw that one person solved it but they deleted the answer. Thank you..